# Distributed file system network booted hosts

Tags: linux, nfs, iscsi, distributed-filesystems

Having task to utilize old servers as a backup distributed file system like MooseFS I see a collision in whole concept:

DFS is fault-tolerant and keep track of HDD status by itself, so any file system carrying data is better used without RAID. Although, OS should be fault-tolerant to HDD failure and should have no probable problems to boot. Using RAID is the best way to achieve that.

In my setup this leaves me poor options:

1. Use two HDD in RAID-1 for OS and other HDDs in JBOD for data, what takes out half of 4xLFF server HDD bays.
2. Use small partition in either LVM or MD mode with a big partition for data, what may bring problems with booting, restoring OS after HDD failure and also break best practices of dedicated HDD for data storage.
3. Network booted hosts with all disks dedicated to storage.

Network booting bring other options up:

1. Hosts can be booted in "root-on-NFS" or in "root-on-iSCSI" mode what make OS files access relatively slow.
2. Hosts can be booted from networked squash file into RAM what make OS fast, but unable to save local data.

My questions are:

Is there a DFS architecture which have no local data stored on a storage server (not metadata server)?

What may happen to DFS if local files (not the stored chunks) are relatively slow?

If there is a way to load OS into RAM, but still have it saved on network backend?